# Azure Search not returning document ID

Tags: azure, search

Im using azure search. I have my id field set as retrievable yet its not getting returned in my search results. Do you guys know why? I only see: document object -> key value, in the search result of an individual document. (Im using the .net SDK)

I want this ID to do a document lookup and serve the real document to the consumer.

```
    public static DocumentSearchResult GetSearchResult(ISearchIndexClient indexClient, string searchTerm)
    {
        SearchParameters parameters;
        DocumentSearchResult results;

        parameters =
            new SearchParameters()
            {
                Select = new[] { "content" }
            };

        results = indexClient.Documents.Search(searchTerm, parameters);

        return results;
    }
```

I found out that i could put ID in searchparameters to retrieve it. This feels unnatural though..

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i could put ID in searchparameters to retrieve it.

```
           parameters =
            new SearchParameters()
            {
                Select = new[] { "content", "id" }
            };
```

As a side note: to serve the document to the caller you need to add the metadata_storage_path to the index (and to the searchparameters to retrieve it as a searchresult)!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Comment: `This feels unnatural though` --> respectfully I disagree. `Select` is completely optional and if you omit this, all retrievable fields are returned. You use `Select` when you want only a few of retrievable fields to return as part of search results.

Comment: In that case it feels natural yes!